# Consume WCF service from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I write WCF service and host in a Managed Windows and add below code in App.config

```
<add baseAddress="http://localhost:1200/000WCF/service"/>
```

but can't call it from a web site,i add **http://localhost:1200/000WCF/service** as service reference but can't find it

App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService"
               behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1200/000WCF/service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:1200

Comment: make sure the service is up.

Comment: the service is running

Comment: Is the windows service hosting the WCF service on the same machine as the web site?  If not, localhost isn't going to work.  Also make sure there aren't any firewall rules blocking port 12000.

Comment: both of them on same machin,no firewall

Comment: Can you post your service config `<system.ServiceModel/>` section please

Comment: just service run is enough?

Comment: Did you check your firewall?

Comment: yes,i don't have any firewall

Comment: Check under what account is your WCF service is running. Try using the command "netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:1200/ user=\everyone" which adds the permissions for port 1200 to be accessible for all users